# Downloading file using PHP pointer

Tags: php, file, download, directory, root

I am storing files above the root directory of my server, and I'm planning on giving users a download by using a php file.

Here is my code:
For the download link:

```
<a href="'.FILEGRAB_ADR.'?adr='.$file.'">Download</a>
```

and for the FileGrab.php file:

```
<?php
//This will grab a file from the server

if (file_exists(UPLOAD_ADR.$_GET['adr'])) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.CATPart"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-length: ".filesize(UPLOAD_ADR.$_GET['adr'])); 

   readfile(UPLOAD_ADR.$_GET['adr']);
   exit;
}
?>
```

I got the above code (in essence) from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

FileGrab.php is loading but it looks like it is just spewing out a raw text form of the file, arbitrary text/symbols etc.

Checked that the file exists, and file size returns a value. Don't know how to get anymore errors to check out of it!

Does it make a difference this is a .CATPart file, which is a little abstract but necessary...

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure to remove any prior `echo` statements or blank lines before `<?php` which might cause the header `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` to not really be written.

Comment: your a saint, it works now :) didn't realise that it was needed for this!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use buffering functions by surrounding your code between ob_start()  and ob_end_flush (); . plus of course make sure that no spaces or echos are used before sending the headers .

For more info check these links:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

[Why use output buffering in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148114/why-use-output-buffering-in-php)